# Postgresql - Conditional SUM with correlated subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the SUM of a CASE condition where one of the conditions uses a correlated subquery to find the results but i'm stuck with the syntax.

Here is a sample of the query that i created until now but with errors:

**Updated**

```
SELECT t1.account,
       t1.date
       SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 THEN t1.amount
                WHEN condition2 THEN (select sum(t2.amount) from t2 where t2.account = t1.account and t2.date = t1.date)
                ELSE 0 END) as total
FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.account, t1.date
```

The above query returns wrong results when the output of the subquery are multiple records. In a nutshell the result of condition2 is sum(t2.amount) * (number of records).

I tried removing the sum() function from the subquery but since it can fetch multiple records i still got an error.

I believe it can be done somehow but i'm stuck.

Can anyone suggest something.

Btw i'm using Postgresql 9.4

Answer (score 2):

You can do an aggregation first.  As phrased, your query would seem to be trying to do this:

```
SELECT t1.account,
       SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 THEN t1.amount
                WHEN condition2 THEN t2.sumamount
                ELSE 0
           END) as total
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t2.account, SUM(t2.amount) as t2.sumamount
      FROM t2
      GROUP BY t2.account
     ) t2
     ON t2.account = t1.account
GROUP BY t1.account
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have updated the query to be more precise to what i want and described the issue with the current behavior of the query. Even with your solution i have the same results. I believe this is due to the double aggregation, outer SUM(). Is there another way to do it avoiding this behaviour?

Comment: @GiannisDim Since you are unable to express the expected output by writing a query you need to show data sample and the expected output as data.